# How to find out the actual times when DST starts/ends for a timezone and particular year?

Tags: .net, timezone, dst

I want to know the exact time when DST starts/ends in a particular timezone and year.

Using `TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules` and `AdjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionStart` I can get a `TransitionTime` object which specifies the DST start moment rule.

Let's assume that I find the adjustment rule that applies for 2010. How do I convert it's `TransitionTime` object to a `DateTime` in 2010?

```
Timezone: (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Valid: 01.01.2007 00:00:00 - 31.12.9999 00:00:00
DST Start TransitionTime:
    IsFixedDateRule: false
    Month: 3
    Week: 2
    DayOfWeek: Sunday
    TimeOfDay: 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSDN has the [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.transitiontime.isfixeddaterule.aspx). See `DisplayTransitionInfo` function at the bottom.

Comment: Weird thing is, `TimeZoneInfo` has a `private static GetDaylightTime(int year, TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule rule)` that returns `DaylightTime` with `Start` and `End` `DateTime` properties. I don't understand why this is private? CLS compliance?